# spring ldap test - custom schema?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-ldap

Is there a way i can load a custom ldap schema when using `org.springframework.ldap.test.TestContextSourceFactoryBean`? E.g. for unit tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using an LDIF file via the [setLdifFile method?](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/test/TestContextSourceFactoryBean.html#setLdifFile(org.springframework.core.io.Resource))

This is the way [RedHat Directory Servers are configured](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/dir-server/cli/8.0/Configuration_Command_File_Reference-Core_Server_Configuration_Reference.html) so maybe you can load a custom schema that way.

Just a thought. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hm... this looks just like what i was looking for. Sadly i'm not able to test it, because i'm working on something else right now.

Looking at the code [1] tells me, that i should give you +15 for this answer =)

 [1] http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/ldap/spring-ldap-test/1.3.0.RELEASE/spring-ldap-test-1.3.0.RELEASE-sources.jar!/org/springframework/ldap/test/TestContextSourceFactoryBean.java?format=ok